# Angular Feature Module Pass Data Dynamically

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out how the feature module works in angular.

I wrapped ComponentA and ServiceA into a feature module ModuleA. ServiceA is needed in ComponentA.
The codes are like:

```
import { ServiceA } from '...
import { ComponentA } from '...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [ComponentA],
    providers: [ServiceA]
})
export class ModuleA { }
```

and

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-a'
})
export class ComponentA {
    constructor(
        private serviceA: SerivceA
    ) { }
```

and

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
    constructor(
        @Inject('SomeData') private someData,
    ) { }

}
```

My problem is that ServiceA needed to be provided with SomeData. This SomeData is changed dynamically in different places in the application, and is obtained by some http call;

How can I use this feature modules with SomeData being provided dynamically? Is this the right way to write a feature module?

Answer (score 3):

Create another Service e.g. SomeDataService, that holds your SomeData.
Provide this service in your application's root module, and inject it into whatever components need it in other modules, instead of injecting the data directly.